# How to find a <br> (or space) from css that I easily found in Inspect Element, to delete it?

Tags: css, element, inspect

I would like to know if someone would be able to help me;
I'm not an export at all in designing websites, but I have come very close to what I want to achieve. The problem I have I can easily find it and fix it on Chrome's 'Inspect Element', but not in the `.css` file.

If you would like to help me, please go to http://www.jordimatas.net/humanitarian and then roll over any of the circular markers, and right click on the gray area on the right of the `tooltip`, to go to 'Inspect Element'. Once 'Inspect Element' opens, it will take you directly to:

```
body > div:nth-child(25) > div > div.center > p
```

Then, if you 'open' p, I would like to erase the line br. Once I erase br, a space on top of the tooltip that I'm trying to remove, disappears.

```
body > div:nth-child(18) > div > div.center > p > br
```

Is there a way for me to erase that space in the `tooltip`, or br in the 'Inspect Element'?

Comment: What are you doing to generate the map markers? It is hard-coded in this JavaScript for jQuery Mapify, the empty `<br>` tag. You need to get a way to modify that, either as part of WordPress plugin or something else you've written.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in modifying or removing the `<br>` alternatively you can do this...

```
br
{
  display: none; /* hide br */
  /*line-height: 0; //set line height to 0 to fix the space issue */ 
}
```

but i will not recommend this. It would be better to remove it from the code.